# Getting a substring based on a length of another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe,

```
       plan_identifier wellthie_issuer_identifier
0  UNM99901AL0000001-DEN                   UNM99902
1  UNM99902AK0000001-DEN                   UNM99902
2  UNM99904AZ0000001-DEN                   UNM99904
3  UNM99905AR0000001-DEN                   UNM99905
4  UNM99906CA0000001-DEN                   UNM99906
5  UNM99908CO0000001-DEN                   UNM99909
6  UNM99909CT0000001-DEN                   UNM99909
```

I need to check if the substring of `plan_identifier` considered after getting the length of `wellthie_issuer_identifier` is equal or not?

Ex- length of `UNM99902` is 8 , so my `plan_identifier` substring = `UNM99901`. Now this should return me False.

So , wherever this is not equal I should get False.

My output should be:-

```
FALSE
TRUE
TRUE
TRUE
TRUE
FALSE
TRUE
```

I tried something like below-

```
print(~(df['plan_identifier'].str[:(df['wellthie_issuer_identifier'].astype(str).str.len())] != df['wellthie_issuer_identifier']))
```

How to achieve this? Can we use apply()?

Comment: Is the position of the identifier important or do you just want to see if it's there?

Comment: Yes .. I need to check on the same row for both the column values

Comment: Sorry, i mean position within the string. Does the identifier have to be at the start?

Comment: Yes . it would be at the start

Answer (score 2):

Using `defchararray.find` from `numpy`

```
s1=df.plan_identifier.values.astype(str)
s2=df.wellthie_issuer_identifier.values.astype(str)    
~np.core.defchararray.find(s1,s2).astype(bool)
 Out[64]: array([False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True])
```

Comment: I am kind of doing a validation of rows. I need the output as a dataframe bool type.

Answer (score 1):

String methods in pandas are ususally very slow. You can use a list comprehension instead. IIUC:

```
>>> [i in p for p,i in zip(df['plan_identifier'],df['wellthie_issuer_identifier'])]
[False, True, True, True, True, False, True]

# or assign to new column:

df['new_column'] = [i in p for p,i in zip(df['plan_identifier'],df['wellthie_issuer_identifier'])]
>>> df
         plan_identifier wellthie_issuer_identifier  new_column
0  UNM99901AL0000001-DEN                   UNM99902       False
1  UNM99902AK0000001-DEN                   UNM99902        True
2  UNM99904AZ0000001-DEN                   UNM99904        True
3  UNM99905AR0000001-DEN                   UNM99905        True
4  UNM99906CA0000001-DEN                   UNM99906        True
5  UNM99908CO0000001-DEN                   UNM99909       False
6  UNM99909CT0000001-DEN                   UNM99909        True
```

**[EDIT]** In a comment, you said that you're only interested in the start of the string. In that case, you can use `startswith` instead:

```
[p.startswith(i) for p,i in zip(df['plan_identifier'],df['wellthie_issuer_identifier'])]
```

Comment: I am kind of doing a validation of rows. I need the output as a dataframe bool type.